# MYSQL error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] al conectar con una base de datos remota

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

me gustaria que por favor me brindaran ayuda con este problema. 
Tengo dos maquinas virtuales en virtualbox  la primera el el servidor web (192.168.0.20 centos 6.8) y la segunda es el servidor de base de datos (192.168.0.50 centos 7)

He creado una aplicación laravel y estoy recibiendo este error en el log

```
local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.50' (13) in /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:119
```

este es mi archivo my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
port = 3337
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

y este es mi archivo .env de laravel

```
B_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.0.50
DB_PORT=3337
DB_DATABASE=darwindeveloper
DB_USERNAME=admindb
DB_PASSWORD=admindb
```

en mi servidor de base de datos ejectuto el siguiente comando

```
mysql -u admindb -h 192.168.0.20 -P 3337 -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.20' (111)
```

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Gracias por su atencion

Comment: Ya le diste permisos en el servidor de destino, para que otros puedan conectarse?

Answer (score 0):

Tu servidor de base de datos esta en 192.168.0.50 y estas intentando conectar con 192.168.0.20???

```
mysql -u admindb -h 192.168.0.20 -P 3337 -p
```

Ya que tienes virtualbox te recomiendo utilizar [Vagrant y Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando crees el usuario para la base de datos en vez de hacerlo de esta manera:

```
'miusuario'@'localhost'
```

crealo de esta manera:

```
'miusuario'@'%'
```

De esta manera le estas diciendo que sera accesible desde un equipo remoto.

Answer (score 0):

1.- No sé en donde tengas tu servidor de base de datos, pero revisa que el puerto 3306 esté abierto, este puerto permite las conexiones remotas.

2.- Para que el servidor permite conexiones remotas debes indicarlo en el archivo my.cnf. Repito, no sé en donde tengas su servidor, pero para:

- Debian/Ubuntu: el archivo estará ubicado en /etc/mysql/my.cnf.
- CentOS/Fedora: el archivo se ubica en /etc/my.cnf

2.- Para editarlo desde consola (si estás usando SSH y dependiendo del SO) puedes usar:

- sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf

3.- Ahora tenemos que enlazar la dirección IP de nuestro servidor MySQL al archivo de configuración. Normalmente, la opción que permite esto está apuntando al localhost (127.0.0.1). Busca o agregue la siguiente línea dentro del archivo (revisa que sea la IP correcta).

```
 bind-address=192.168.0.20
```

4.- Verifica que la opción # skip-networking esté comentada (que tenga el signo numeral # al principio), si no lo está agregue el signo # para comentarla.

5.- Guarda el archivo

6.-  Reinicia apache

7.- Desde la consola MySQL local (o desde phpmyadmin), dale permisos a tu usuario para acceder a la base de datos, por ejemplo para el usuario root sin contraseña (modifícalo por tu usuario y contraseña):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY "";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT all ON *.* TO root@'localhost';
```

8.- Reinicia MySQL.

Éxito.